# Rails how to put hash as parameter into url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, get

Since I have one hash object which needs to be passed into `GET` request.
The hash should look like this

```
@filter = {
  "type" => "credit",
  "status" => "1",
  "invoice_type" => "1"
}
```

I make the request URL in this way

```
@report_url = "#{url}?filter=#{@filter}"
```

However, in this case, when I access `params[:filter]` in that GET controller, it will be `"{"`.

How do I make it become

```
{
  "type" => "credit",
  "status" => "1",
  "invoice_type" => "1"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
@report_url = url + "?" + { filter: @filter }.to_query
```